# error C2512: no appropriate default constructor available: declaration of a object with arguments! inside a constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a problem with constructors.
I have two classes (MyClass1, MyClass2).

MyClass1.h

```
class MyClass1 {
public:
    MyClass1();
    ...
private:
    MyClass2 object;
    ...
}
```

MyClass1.cpp

```
#include "MyClass1.h"

MyClass1::MyClass1() {      //This constructor causes the error!!!
    object = MyClass2(1000);
    ...
}

...
```

MyClass2.h

```
class MyClass2 {
public:
    MyClass2(int);
    ...
private:
    int id;
    ...
}
```

MyClass2.cpp

```
#include "MyClass2.h"

MyClass2::MyClass2(int id) {
    this->id = id;
    ...
}
...
```

When creating an instance of 'MyClass1' i get this error message:

```
error C2512: 'MyClass2': no appropriate default constructor available
```

Comment: Use an initializer list to initialize the member variable instead of doing that in the constructor body.

Comment: Where is the `#include "MyClass2.h"` in `MyClass1.cpp`? Seems like that should be there, since you reference `MyClass2`.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to *assign* `object` inside the constructor's body, before that `object` need to be default-constructed, but `MyClass2` doesn't have the default constructor.

You should use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Explanation) to specify which constructor should be used to initialize `object`.

> Before the compound statement that forms the function body of the constructor begins executing, initialization of all direct bases, virtual bases, and non-static data members is finished. Member initializer list is the place where non-default initialization of these objects can be specified.

e.g.

```
MyClass1::MyClass1() : object(1000) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that when entering the body of the constructor every member should have been constructed and initialized. As tehre is no ctor with no paramater available for `MyClass2` compiler complains.

Syntax to initialize a member object is:

```
MyClass1::MyClass1() : object(1000) {}
```